# Unable to create new IOS-release for Kotlin Multiplatform project after updating dependencies

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I recently updated some dependencies for our Kotlin Multiplatform project, and now I am unable to create a new IOS-release. Here are the dependencies that were updated:

```
multiplatform 1.6.10 -> 1.8.10
plugin.serialization 1.6.10 -> 1.8.10
ktor 1.6.7 -> 2.2.2.
kotlinx-serialization-core 1.2.2. -> 1.4.1
```

The error message that I am receiving is as follows:

```
Execution failed for task ':linkReleaseFrameworkIosArm64'
'org.gradle.api.provider.Provider org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinNativeLink.getIntermediateLibrary()'
```

I am not sure where to begin with debugging this issue. Running --debug/--info/--warning-mode=all does not provide much information. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `gradlew clean`?

Comment: Yeah, tried cleaning but to no avail.

Comment: Try to downgrade the multiplatform to 1.8.0, 1.8.10 released today, and it might not be stable enough.

Comment: This comment (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52982#focus=Comments-27-6228113.0-0) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. There were other dependencies in the project that had to be updated because of conflincting Gradle-versions.

Comment: which gradle-version do you use?